# Usage of Apollo Lunar Surface Hasselblad Camera with 500 mm lens?

Tags: photography, apollo-program

Here is a [list](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap16fj/02photoequip.html) of photographic cameras used for Apollo 16.

There were two [Lunar Surface Data Hasselblads](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11-hass.html) equipped with a 60 mm lens for both astronauts to be used with chest mounts to the space suits. The astronauts had special training to use them without viewfinder. The astronauts were very successful in aiming with their cameras.

But what about the third Lunar Surface Hasselblad Camera with a 500 mm lens? Using a 500 mm lens without viewfinder would be difficult. The Camera was used with 70 mm film, the image size was about 53 X 53 mm. For 35 mm film and 24 x 36 mm format, the equivalent focal length would be about 288 mm.

Did they use the original waist-level viewfinder of the Hasselblad single-lens reflex cameras? Was this camera used only without helmet inside the pressurized cabin of the the Lunar Module or was it used also with closed helmet on the Moon's surface? Or was a special designed viewfinder for use in space added?

Comment: I usually think of lens focal lengths in terms of the equivalent for a 35mm format camera. Did these cameras have 35mm film, or something larger? If larger, what would be the equivalents of 60mm and 500mm?

Comment: @uhoh usually the 500EL is fitted with a 120 film back for 6x6cm medium format, but for Apollo use it was fitted with a special back to take 70mm film cartridges. So the crop factor should be somewhere around 0.35 to 0.4 relative to 35mm (not 0.5 because the "raw" film sizes include the perfs), and a 500mm lens would be around 175 - 200 mmE.

Comment: (the 70mm film is mentioned by both links in the question)

Comment: @hobbs thanks for going into some depth. Being "[exceedingly stupid](https://youtu.be/OAnwYfEUtLw?t=61)" I would have used the 0.5 multiplier ;-)

Comment: If I calculate the crop factor based on the format diagonal, for 35 mm film and 24 x 36 mm format, the diagonal is 43.27 mm. For 70 mm film and 53 x 53 mm format the diagonal is 74.95 mm. The crop factor is thus 0.58 and a 500 mm lens would be around 288 mm. The negative format should be the same as that of the 60 mm [Biogon lens](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/Biogon5.6_60mm_ZEISS.pdf).

Comment: I've used your link [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31310/12102) thanks!

Comment: @uhoh: It is a pleasure to me if my links are reused.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should be an [image](https://newatlas.com/apollo-15-camera-auction/30692/#p252165) of the Hasselblad camera with the 500 mm lens.

[image]

The part at the right of the image (behind the film magazine) could be part of an iron sight similar to that used for firearms. The other alignment marker is at the left top of the image, the small black part above the lens. See the red arrows.

Using this viewfinder it was possible to align the camera to an object that should be in the center of the image. But it was not possible to see the borders of the image.

Another [image](http://www.ninfinger.org/karld/My%20Space%20Museum/apollocams.htm) of an astronaut training the use of the 500 mm lens:

[image]

No doubt anymore that the 500 mm lens should be used with a closed helmet during a moonwalk.

A [datasheet](http://hasselbladhistorical.eu/pdf/lds/C500.pdf) of the Tele-Tessar f/8 - 500 mm lens. Another [500 mm lens](http://hasselbladhistorical.eu/pdf/lds/CF500.pdf) for the Hasselblad camera, but not the one used for Apollo.

Answer (score 21):

As it happens, on Apollo 17, Gene Cernan got a picture of Jack Schmitt using a handheld camera with the 500mm lens on the surface of the moon! At the [Station 6](http://lroc.sese.asu.edu/posts/759) site, Schmitt braced himself against a boulder and took some "manual panorama" series of pictures of the area. This picture is from [magazine 146/F](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/images17.html#MagF).

[image]

According to the Apollo 17 image library:

> AS17-146-22293
>   165:49:31 Station 6. "Locator" to the LRV, with Jack in the background taking photos AS17-139-21206 to 21211 and using Fragment 2 to give him some stability. Fragment 3 is the smaller piece of rock that is next to Fragment 2 and to the right of Jack.

Here is Dave Scott on A15 brandishing the 500mm:

[image]

Comment: Jack Schmitt really looks like using an eye-level viewfinder. Definately not the waist-level viewfinder of an unmodified Hasselblad SLR. Does he wear also the chest mount data camera?

Comment: In https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/AS17-146-22296HR.jpg taken 8 minutes later, Schmitt does appear to have the chest mounted camera with  60mm lens.

Comment: Not sure whether he's using one camera body and switching lenses -- given lunar dust, that seems fraught.

Comment: In this [list](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap16fj/02photoequip.html), only the camera used in the CM is listed with three different lenses 80, 250 and 105 mm for interchangement. All lunar cameras are listed with one single lens only.

Comment: Here is a long [list](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/images17.html) with many images taken with the 500 mm lens.

Comment: This [image](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/AS17-139-21204.jpg) taken with the 500 mm lens showing the LM from a distance. The LM is nearly perfect centered, impossible without a viewfinder for a 500 mm lens.

Comment: @Uwe: You don’t need to modify a 500-series Hasselblad to use an eye-level viewfinder—it’s a modular system. Swapping the waist-level viewfinder for an eye-level viewfinder is no more of a modification than swapping out the lens.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: Using the standard waist-level viewfinder or an eye-level viewfinder was not possible because of the reseau plates mounted. The reseau plate with the cross marks was used for the 60 and the 500 mm lens. See this [image](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/AS17-139-21204.jpg). The mirror of the SLR was removed to place the reseau plate. The camera was no longer an SLR.

Answer (score 8):

The best location I know for the Apollo images are the hi-res scans put up at the [Apollo Archive](http://www.apolloarchive.com/apollo_gallery.html).  Unfortunately, the images don't seem to be broken out explicitly by camera, but in the Hasselblad Magazines section for Apollo 16 there are some that explicitly have 500mm in their name. It doesn't mention how they were taken, but the few I looked at do not appear to be taken through the lander window.

Edit:  You might find [this resource](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/apollo.photechnqs.htm) useful.  In Part I it lists the 500mm Hasselblad as a "handheld" camera.  It talks about how Hasselblad removed the SLR part of the camera and replaced it with a straight-through viewfinder that was then modified to be used with a helmet on.

Comment: I found three photo follwing your link, the AS16-112-18247, AS16-112-18254 and AS16-112-18254. I agree, these images dont look like taken through a window.

Comment: Look at [www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-reseau.html](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-reseau.html).  The Hasselblad apparently was the 500EL.  I think it took either the 60 or 500mm lens.

Comment: This [list](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap16fj/02photoequip.html) counts 3 Hasselblad cameras on board of the LM. Two of them equiped with a 60 mm lens and one with a 500 mm. No need to change lenses with pressurized space suit gloves and moon dust all around.

Comment: Interesting, except that I find it almost iimpossible to get a sharp image with the 500mm apotessar CF without mirror lockup and a sturdy tripod. Handheld is very questionable !!!