# Were panoramic images taken during Apollo 15 planned and trained before on Earth?

Tags: the-moon, training, imaging

I followed a link in an answer to the [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31681/were-stereoscopic-pictures-taken-during-the-apollo-missions) about stereoscopic images and found a long [list](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/images15.html#Pans) with panoramic images composed from images shot with the lunar Hasselblad cameras.

For instance the ALSEP [pan](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15pan1473840.jpg) at the end of EVA 2, assembled by Dave Byrne.
[image]
Made from 17 separate images, more than 360 °, see the shadow of photographing astronaut at the left and right side of the image.

I tried automatic stiching of the same images using a free demo version of [AutoStich](http://matthewalunbrown.com/autostitch/autostitch.html) with a very good result without any manual intervention:
[image]

Automatic stiching requires overlapping images. This is easy using a good standard camera viewfinder but difficult using the modified Hasselblad cameras wearing a space suit helmet.

Did the astronauts train taking overlapping panoramic images on Earth? Without using a [panoramic tripod head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panoramic_tripod_head), just using a handheld or suit mounted camera?

Using the 60 mm Biogon lens from Zeiss with a horizontal angular field of 47 ° the astronaut had to turn for a full 360 ° panorama of 16 images about 22 ° after each shot. But there is a tolerance from about 17 to 42 ° as long as the mean value is close to 22.5 ° and each pair of images overlaps at least 5 °.

But there were also [panoramic](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15pan1232130.jpg) images taken with the 500 mm lens.
[image]

See this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30873/usage-of-apollo-lunar-surface-hasselblad-camera-with-500-mm-lens) about the 500 mm lens and its viewfinder.
Due to the very small horizontal angular field of only 6.5 ° overlapping did not work well for all 5 images. There are a lot of other panoramic images with successful overlapping done with the 500 mm lens.

A panorama taken at Station 2 of Trophy Point using the 500 mm lens, assembly by Dave Byrne:
[image]

No problems with overlapping, but a constant small rotation of the camera around its optical axis.

Comment: having the camera strapped to the chest probably helped rather than hindered

Comment: The strapped camera to the chest may helped to keep the camera horizontally aligned, but did not help to turn about 22 ° after each shot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, yes.  The book "[Science Training History of the Apollo Astronauts"](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/strategies/Phinney_NASA-SP-2015-626.pdf) mentions training for photographic panoramas in several places. (These quotes may not be specific to Apollo 15 but it's clear from the book that it was common to all missions).

> Muehlberger  describes  the  procedure for the panoramas that were
>   taken at each station just after the crew dismounted from the Rover: 
>   “The first guy off goes out a short distance and takes a 360
>   - degree film panorama while the other  guy’s getting all the tools out, and this sort of thing, and getting ready to start work.  While
>   this guy’s doing this panorama, he’s sort of looking around and saying
>   ‘Well, there’s a rock over there we’d  better sample, and we’d better
>   do our core over here , ’ trying to design what’s going to happen in 
>   these next few minutes that was assigned to that place.  Th e
>   panoramas were important because after  they were all done, before
>   they left, then the other guy took one from a different place, and
>   that one  showed, of course, all their footprints.  You could check to
>   see which rocks were now missing.  You  could add in some other
>   details that way.  If they still didn’t know where they were, you
>   could use  those two panoramas, because there’s now a stereobase, and
>   you could look at the distant mountains  and play triangulation games
>   and locate the actual craters they were  standing by on the Moon”
>
> “ Panoramas were taken at each station to permit precise location of
>   the station by resection and  to illustrate and supplement geologic
>   descriptions by the crew.  A complete panorama consists of 15 or more
>   overlapping photographs, covering a total of 360 ° .  The overlap
>   zones between  pictures in  panoramas can  be viewed stereoscopically
>   because the aiming direction of the camera was changed  and the lens
>   position was shifted slightly each time a picture was taken.  This
>   provides a stereoscopic  baseline a few centimeters long, which is useful for study of topography within 50 to 100 m of the  camera. 
>   Pictures were taken with a 500
>   - mm focal length lens on a Hasselblad camera to permit study  of features inaccessible to the crew.

Appendix P gives a memo listing "Documented Sample Photographic Procedures for Apollo 16", included is the panorama procedure.

[image]

For an Apollo 15 specific reference, here's a panorama called out in the [cuff checklist](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15lsp.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! On page 170 there is nice diagramm for panoramic images. 12 images for a full circle, 3 for each quadrant. A rotation of 30° is well suited for visual judgment and fits well to the horizontal angular field of 47 ° of the used 60 mm lens. But "changes in direction ≥ 45 °" ? It should read "changes in direction ≤ 45 °".

Comment: Agreed! That seems to be the formal version of the diagram sketched out in Appendix P of the book.

Answer (score 5):

From the book ["Science Training History of the Apollo Astronauts"](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/strategies/Phinney_NASA-SP-2015-626.pdf), link from Organic Marble's excellent answer on page 138:
[image]

Overlapping the images for a panorama was learned by try and error during the field exercises. Developing and mounting the panoramas was done during the night by a special photo lab team. What took hours in the photo lab is done today in some minutes using a digital camera and a laptop.