# How often did Apollo astronauts wear red helmets?

Tags: nasa, astronauts, identify-this-object, spacesuits

Images of NAsA astronaut David R. Scott performing a spacewalk during Apollo 9 show a red helmet.

When did NASA's use of red-colored helmets begin, and when did it end, and was there a special name for these?

- https://archive.org/details/AS09-20-3064
- https://archive.org/details/AS09-20-3069

Cropped from [AS09-20-3064](https://archive.org/details/AS09-20-3064)  Apollo 9, David R. Scott spacewalk (found in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39996/12102)):

[image]

Comment: I was in the process of writing a question about where this picture was taken from, but sadly the answer to *that* (not the answer to your question) is on wikipedia.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've since deleted the Wikipedia reference from that post and replaced it with the archive.org link. Since it was within five minutes, the Wikipedia link is not present in the edit review, and now I don't remember the link.

Comment: No problem! I was just reading about the mission on Wikipedia, I didn't follow a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time, apparently.

But mostly they had a white thermal cover over them.

This is Neal Armstrong's Apollo 11 helmet from [here](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/A11NAAFlownSuit.html).

[image]

Apparently credible but unsourced discussion here: http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum14/HTML/000900.html (see "Matt T"'s comments).